# Crashes in snow leopard, not leopard

Tags: cocoa

I have an application called Flick Background (I'm the developer).  It works fine on Leopard, but doesn't work on Snow Leopard (crashes when downloading an image).  Here is the crash log (some is removed, because it contains personal information):

```
Process:         Flick Background [8591]
Path:            <<hidden>>
Identifier:      com.alexy.Flick Background

Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Codes: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x0000000020a38928
Crashed Thread:  0  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread

Thread 0 Crashed:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
0   libobjc.A.dylib                   0x916caee4 objc_msgSend + 36
1   com.apple.CFNetwork               0x969ac054 URLDownload::willSendRequest(_CFURLRequest const*, _CFURLResponse*) + 56
2   com.apple.CFNetwork               0x9694a0a7 URLConnectionClient::getRequestForTransmission(_CFURLResponse*, _CFURLRequest const*, __CFError**) + 413
3   com.apple.CFNetwork               0x96949b2f URLConnectionClient::_clientWillSendRequest(_CFURLRequest const*, _CFURLResponse*, URLConnectionClient::ClientConnectionEventQueue*) + 223
4   com.apple.CFNetwork               0x969ce456 URLConnectionClient::ClientConnectionEventQueue::processAllEventsAndConsumePayload(XConnectionEventInfo<XClientEvent, XClientEventParams>*, long) + 148
5   com.apple.CFNetwork               0x9694994e URLConnectionClient::processEvents() + 94
6   com.apple.CFNetwork               0x969497ef MultiplexerSource::perform() + 183
7   com.apple.CoreFoundation          0x910d90fb __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 1563
8   com.apple.CoreFoundation          0x910d6bbf __CFRunLoopRun + 1071
9   com.apple.CoreFoundation          0x910d6094 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 452
10  com.apple.CoreFoundation          0x910d5ec1 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 97
11  com.apple.HIToolbox               0x94426f9c RunCurrentEventLoopInMode + 392
12  com.apple.HIToolbox               0x94426c8d ReceiveNextEventCommon + 158
13  com.apple.HIToolbox               0x94426bd6 BlockUntilNextEventMatchingListInMode + 81
14  com.apple.AppKit                  0x91bbba89 _DPSNextEvent + 847
15  com.apple.AppKit                  0x91bbb2ca -[NSApplication nextEventMatchingMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:] + 156
16  com.apple.AppKit                  0x91b7d55b -[NSApplication run] + 821
17  com.apple.AppKit                  0x91b755ed NSApplicationMain + 574
18  com.alexy.Flick Background        0x00001cfa start + 54
```

What I'm seeing is that when the image downloads, my application crashes.  My first conclusion is that what I'm using to download the image is depreciated in snow leopard.

I don't have a snow leopard machine, so I cannot locate the error directly.  This is part of the code that I might think is causing the problem:

```
    NSError *error = nil;
NSData *initalizedUrl = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL: [NSURL URLWithString:@"URLHERE"] options:0 error:&error];
NSString *rawContents = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:initalizedUrl encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
```

I am almost 100% sure that this issue will be resolved in snow leopard.

Comment: Why do you think that code is causing the problem? What does your crash log look like after you symbolicate it? (You *are* saving the dSYM bundle from each one of your releases, right?)

Comment: I think it's this code because this is the only function that downloads something.  I moved my main window around rapidly and I was leaking hundreds of objects, I found out later.  I didn't even start the downloading process.  Hmm...

Comment: Well, if you don't release the NSString object, that'd be one of the leaks. The Leaks instrument will tell you more. You still should symbolicate the crash log; then you will be able to go to the exact lines of your code your program was at when it crashed.

Comment: How do I symbolicate the crash log?

Comment: I did release the NSString object, I can supply source code if needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue was fixed by upgrading to snow leopard.